# Ratchet websocket with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ratchet

Is there a way to share session variable between codeigniter and ratchet PHP websocket?

I want to identify user when he connect to websocket

Comment: IF YOU GOOGLED YOUR QUESTION YOU MIGHT HAVE FOUND THIS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813183/setup-codeigniter-and-rachet-socket

Comment: Hi, this post doesn't solve my problem because there is no session variable.